# Не срабатывает событие scroll

Tags: jquery

```js
$(document).on("scroll", "div", function() {
  console.info('scroll');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="overflow:scroll;height:100px">
Text<br>Text<br>Text<br>Text<br>Text<br>Text<br>Text<br>Text<br>Text<br>Text<br>Text<br>Text<br>Text<br>Text<br>Text<br>Text<br>Text<br>Text<br>Text<br>Text<br>Text<br>Text<br>Text<br>
</div>
```

Пытаюсь поймать событие `scroll` через `on`, но страница прокручивается, а событие не срабатывает. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: В данном случае вы должны использовать `$("div").scroll(function() { }` (см. подробнее [здесь](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/))

Comment: @RifmaMan объект загружается динамически, таким образом я не смогу получить к нему доступ

Comment: Просто также генерируйте событие с появлением объекта, по другому боюсь (используя `$(document).on...)` сделать не получится!

Comment: Делаю так `$(document).find('div').scroll(function() {...}` но с динамически загруженными не работает

Comment: Вы немножко не поняли, событие вы сможете лишь статически объявить, если объект появляется динамически, то и событие нужно вешать лишь после его появления в скрипте, в ходе выполнения которого объект и появляется, если бы вы описали вопрос точней, ответ был бы наглядней!

Comment: @RifmaMan через addEventListener решил проблему

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.addEventListener('scroll', function(event) {
  if (event.target.id === 'scroll') {
    console.log('scrolling', event.target);
  }
}, true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="overflow:scroll;height:100px" id="scroll">
  Text<br>Text<br>Text<br>Text<br>Text<br>Text<br>Text<br>Text<br>Text<br>Text<br>Text<br>Text<br>Text<br>Text<br>Text<br>Text<br>Text<br>Text<br>Text<br>Text<br>Text<br>Text<br>Text<br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема заключается в том, что событие [`scroll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scroll_event) не всплывает. Из-за этого вариант с jquery не работает, так как событие не доходит до элемента, на который вешается обработчик.

Для решения можно воспользоваться возможностью поставить обработчик на фазу захвата. Это можно сделать с помощью третьего параметра [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)